# Can I not use SharedPreference inside a constructor?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using a simple class to perform some actions (calculations) and want to write a value in SharedPreferences that may later be used.

However, this is not working. I extended the class from Activity so that I can use the `getSharedPReferences()` method. Is this incorrect and not allowed?

I'm getting a null pointer exception trying to initialize the sharedpreference editor

Code below:

```
public class JSONParser extends Activity {

    // To store our preferences for JSON route info
    public static final String MY_PREFS_JSON = "JSONPrefs";

    // Construct an object with JSON values
    public JSONParser(String JSONString){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
            JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            // fails with NullPointer            
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_JSON, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 

            // Store in SharedPreferences our JSON value
            editor.putString("JSON", routesArray.toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Adding error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The activity context is not created till `onCreate()` gets invoked. So, if you want to do something which involves the `context` then do it in `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
            JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            // fails with NullPointer            
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_JSON, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 

            // Store in SharedPreferences our JSON value
            editor.putString("JSON", routesArray.toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

So in your case - pass the `JSONString` to your activity using `intent.putExtra()` when you are starting your activity and fetch it in `onCreate()` using `getIntent().getStringExtra()`

Comment: Updated the answer with how to pass `JSONString` to your activity.

Comment: No,this doesn't solve my problem. This class is infact a "normal" class made into an Activity just to use SharedpReferences. In fact an object of this class type is being created by another class which again is not an activity. Maybe there is an alternate way to achieve what I"m doing -- i.e. to save something that maybe accessed in some other activity some other time

Comment: If that's the case, pass your application context using `getApplicationContext()`  all the way from the launcher activity to the class where you want to use prefs. and use that context to save your prefs in any method of your class(activity or non-activity).

Answer (score 2):

Activities can not have alternate constructors (or maybe more appropriately they should not). Activities must only have a default, empty constructor.

Also, you can not obtain system services inside an Activity's constructor.  None of them have been created yet, so they will all return null.

You have to wait until `Activity#onCreate()` to retrieve the SharedPreferences.

```
public class JSONParser extends Activity {

    public static final String PARAM_JSON = "json";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       String json = getIntent().getStringExtra(PARAM_JSON);
       if (json == null || json.trim().isEmpty() {
          finish();
          return;
       }
       // do stuff with json.
    }
}
```

Then start it with the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, JSONParser.class);
intent.putExtra(JSONParser.PARAM_JSON, jsonString);
```

Comment: so what is the solution to write some value into SharedPreference via a normal class? Or alternatively, I want to store a particular string value (JSON value) that maybe used at some future point elsewhere in another activity